# Why is this DMAX not working?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following:

Textfield called: WoNr
Table column called: Workorder

```
= DMax("[WoNr]","[Workorder]","[Workorder]") + 1
```

In the text field named WoNr I have entered the code above, I get an error.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `"[Workorder]"` as the criterion (i.e., the last parameter)? Try the following:

```
= DMax("WoNr", "Workorder")
```

If this works, continue reading.

Now about the "+ 1" thing. You say that WoNr is a text field (rather than a numeric field). So, what do you want to get? Do you want to append "1" to the string (WoNr = "D1" => Result = "D11") or is WoNr actually a numeric value and you want to add 1? In any case, you should make your intention clear. For string concatenation, use `&`:

```
= DMax("WoNr", "Workorder") & "1"
```

for arithmetic operations, convert your text into an appropriate numeric data type first:

```
= CLng(DMax("WoNr", "Workorder")) + 1
```

Comment: The first thing doesnt work. It says something like this: The systax of the expression in invalid an opperator or  (i had to translate it from dutch to english) the textfield is set to nummeric, the textfield name = WoNr, the column name = Workorder in table KlntInfo I want to add +1 to the last record number in table KlntInfo

Comment: Or should it be like this: = DMAX("textfield", "table") + 1

Comment: @Chris: If your system is Dutch, you might have to use a semicolon as a separator rather than a comma (i.e. `=DMax("WoNr"; "Workorder")`). [I know that it's that way in German, because we use the comma as a decimal separator.]

Comment: yes, it's in dutch indeed. the example expression does give a ; indeed, i'll try it right away.

Comment: I think that was the error, something is still wrong, but I will ask that in a new thread.